# How to test iPad retina app with simulator on 13 inch Macbook Pro?

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, ios-simulator

Even at 50% scale and with my resolution at max, I can't see the whole ipad simulator window on my 13 inch Macbook Pro.  Any way to zoom it out more?

Comment: I sympathize, but have no answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a somewhat usable workaround: set the zoom to 100%, then you can scroll around to see the whole screen.  You can't scroll to off-monitor portions of the screen at 50 or 25%.

Comment: how to do it can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but not possible, I'm on a 13 inch Air and have the same problem. Considering this is the minimum allowed zoom on the simulator, you'll just have to stick with the non-retina simulator.

Comment: I think all we can really do is hope for it in an update. Their engineers probably have this same gripe with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

they did add a 25% option in 4.5.2 it seems however you would still have to scroll to view the ipad retina screen when rotated to portrait. It would be nice if they made the minimum even lower like 5% in steps of 5%.